# Glassfish Realm Netbeans 8.0.2 Glassfish 4.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I'm working on a web application trying to secure access to JSP for logged users I decided to use glassfish realms I've done lots of tutorials from the internet but the problem is always the same.

I can't log in, is it because most of the tutorials are using glassfish 3.x?

I've seen similar post here but no one gave an answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>admin</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>prywatne</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/prywatne/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>annRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You didn't even ask a question...

Comment: What possible go wrong? everything is exactly the same as on few tutorials like this http://blog.eisele.net/2011/01/jdbc-security-realm-and-form-based.html And it wont log in The only different is version of glasfish and netbeans

Comment: In most cases the problem is in front of the monitor (OSI level 8). Nobody can guess what exactly you have tried when you don't describe it with more details...

Comment: Well i cant post images yet to show everything. What about this  OSI level 8? what i've done i just exactly like in this tutorial- simple test-done database (two tables one users (username password) second roles (username, role) done jdbc pool, resources, done everything in web.xml and sun-web.xml Done folder "protected" with one html file inside This folder is in url pattern at security constrait  i got all grups etc Push run file (form protected folder) login (basic, default) windows show up in webrowser so im puttin username and password like i got in database and nothing

Comment: Please edit the question and add your `web.xml` (text, you don't need to post an image).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you didn't setup the `FacesServlet` in your `web.xml`.

Add the following in your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>loginForm.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

You can also change the **welcome-file** if you want.

**See also:**

- [The Java EE 6 Tutorial  - Basic Requirements of a JavaServer Faces Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaxj.html)

Comment: is it have to contain jsf? Im just looked ad java_ee_6_development_with_netbeans_7 book and there is nothing with jsf But the weird thing that even example from this book is not working

Comment: Yes, if you write XHTML code like in the tutorial this is JSF and you need the entries in your `web.xml` to "enable" it.

Comment: Yes but you don't want to use JSP. It is an old and deprecated technique and shouldn't be used in new projects.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to install the MySQL driver for Glassfish.

Comment: i've done the driver connection is working now I've done another test When i used realmname FILE its working but when i use my own realm it keep asking to login even if put exactly what in database (username and password) Glasfish log for this is    "Severe:   jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason
Warning:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception" What can couse this? In realm i set Password Encryptio Algorithm to NONE

Answer (score 0):

Problem sorted thanks to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xsU6juUZd0

i didnt use encryption so i put none. anyway the problems was that in realm in user table and group table only table name is not enough but pattern databasename.tablename helps